# Show that there are no compact surfaces that have negative Gauss curvature everywhere

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, surfaces

Let $S$ be a compact surface and let $h: S \longrightarrow \Bbb{R}$ be the height function with respect to a given plane. By compactness, there is a minimum point $p$, at which the hessian $(d^2h)_p$ is semi-definite positive. On the other hand, we know that 
$$
(d^2h)_p(v) = \sigma_p(v, v), \quad v \in T_pS
$$ 
where $\sigma_p$ is the second fundamental form at $p$. Hence $\sigma_p$ is semi-definite positive and hence its determinant is non-negative. Hence the Gauss curvature at $p$ is non-negative.

My question is:

> Why can we conclude that $\sigma_p$ is semi-definite positive?

The motivation is Exercise 3.40 in *Curves and Surfaces*, second edition, by Montiel and Ros, and whose solution is presented above:

> Show that there are no compact surfaces that have negative Gauss curvature everywhere.

Comment: I think it's analogous to (or probably even follows from) the fact that a real function is locally *convex* (its second derivative is $\ge0$) at its local minimum points: any direction you choose from $p$, the value of $h$ must increase (nondecrease) while moving that direction.

Comment: For another — arguably more geometric — argument see Proposition 3.5 on pp. 61-62 of my (free) differential geometry text (link in my profile).

Comment: @Berci thank you for your comment, but this is an argument to help understand that $(d^2h)_p$ is semi-definite positive, right? I get this. Now, we want to prove that $\sigma_p(v, w) \geq 0$ for every $v, w \in T_pS$. But from the equality in the question we only know that $\sigma_p(v, v) \geq 0, \ v \in T_pS$. I do not understand how this implies what we need.

Comment: @TedShifrin I will centainly take a look, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most direct answer to your question is obtained by taking $v$ to be the eigenvectors of $\sigma_p$. The determinant of $\sigma_p$ is the product of the eigenvalues, which are nonnegative.

Comment: Let $v_1, v_2$ be the eigenvectors. Then $\sigma_p(v_1, v_1) = \lambda_1 v_1^Tv_1 \geq 0 \implies \lambda_1 \geq 0$, and the same for $\lambda_2$. Hence $\det = \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \geq 0$. Is this your argument?

Comment: Yup, perfect. Makes sense to you?

Comment: Totally, thank you very much! Also, your solution in the book is very interesting, thanks for sharing it with us for free!